# Why some scripts can be imported and executed from another scripts and some scripts cause FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I have these two scripts and I can execute `file1` from `file2`:

```
[xxx]$ ls
file1  file2

[xxx]$ cat file1
#!/usr/bin/python3
def main():
    print("hello")
main()

[xxx]$ cat file2
#!/usr/bin/python3
exec(open("file1").read())

[xxx]$ ./file2
hello
```

So this works fine. But I have another, a lot longer code and when I try to execute it, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/executed/script/", line 347, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/to/executed/script/", line 340, in main
    exec(open("scipt_that_is_called_in_the_executed_script").read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'scipt_that_is_called_in_the_executed_script'
```

What could cause this and how do I get rid of the error?

Comment: you gave a relative path which in Python is relative to your current work directory, not the script location. Does it work with an absolute path?

Comment: The  `cmd` tag is for Microsoft Windws cmd.exe. I this is not about Windows, please remove the tag.